# Generating discrete random numbers under constraints

Tags: python, random

I have a problem that I'm not sure how to solve properly.

Suppose we have to generate *1 <= n <= 40* numbers: `X[1], X[2], ..., X[n]`.

For each number, we have some discrete space we can draw a number from. This space is not always a range and can be quite large (thousands/millions of numbers).

Another constraint is that the resulting array of numbers should be sorted in ascending order: `X[1] <= X[2] <= ... <= X[n]`.

As an example for three numbers:

`X[1] in {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31}`

`X[2] in {10, 20, 30, 50}`

`X[3] in {1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003}`

Examples of valid outputs for this test: `[9, 20, 2001]`, `[18, 30, 1995]`

Example of invalid outputs for this test: `[25, 10, 1998]` (not increasing order)

I already tried different methods but what I'm not satisfied with is that they all yield not uniformly distributed results, i.e. there is a strong bias in all my solutions and some samples are underrepresented.

One of the methods is to try to randomly generate numbers one by one and at each iteration reduce the space for the upcoming numbers to satisfy the increasing order condition. This is bad because this solution always biases the last numbers towards the higher end of their possible range.

I already gave up on looking for an exact solution that could yield samples uniformly. I would really appreciate any reasonable solution (preferably, on Python, but anything will do, really).

Comment: Please update your question with your best code so far.

Comment: Each time you pick a number, delete all value that are less than its value in the next sampling universes

Comment: You really have 2 solutions. Brute force: precompute all possible outcomes in a list, then draw equally randomly from it.  Or do some possibly non trivial math with conditional probabilities while you draw your X[i]'s one at a time...

Comment: Are the constraints always satisfiable?

Comment: If the constraints are easy to satisfy (e.g. most numbers in one set lie below most numbers in the next set) a hit or miss approach is reasonable. On the other hand, if the constraints are hard to satisfy then the idea of @Julien to enumerate all solutions and then sample from that might be feasible. You might want to ask on [mathematics.se] for approaches to generate uniform samples from the set of increasing sequences in a cartesian product.

Comment: @quamrana I updated the question with a description of my approach.

Comment: @Mayeulsgc This is what I've considered, and I think, this is bad because this solution always biases the last numbers towards the higher end of their possible range.

Comment: @Swistack: I see no code.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes, the constraints are guaranteed to be feasible! I'll try to ask this in Mathematics section, thank you.

Comment: @quamrana Discussions of algoriithms are on-topic on Stack Overflow. OP added a description of the algorithm they tried, a description which is easy enough to code. Seeing the code itself wouldn't add much here.

Comment: @Julien I can have about 20-30 numbers to generate and the number of options is too high to generate the list explicitly but thank you!

Comment: @JohnColeman: Ok, I'll remember that,

Comment: What if you started with a random permutation of the index set and do the sampling according to that permutation. Once you pick a number -- delete some smaller numbers in some sets  (those from larger indices not yet chosen from) and delete some larger numbers from other sets (those from smaller indices not yet chosen).

Comment: @JohnColeman that is a more clever heuristics, thank you! But Julien gave the answer that describes the exactly uniform sampling process, I will try it.

Comment: Yes there is a bias in a way but the lower end of the range won't fullfill the constraints anyway so will be judge invalid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I won't code it for you but here's the logic to do the non brute force approach:

Let's define N(i,x) the number of possible samples of X[1],...,X[i] where X[i]=x. And S(i) the possible values for X[i]. You have the recursion formula N(i,x) = Sum over y in S(i-1) with y<=x of N(i-1,y). This allows you to very quickly compute all N(i,x). It is then easy to build up your sample from the end:

Knowing all N(n,x), you can draw X[n] from S(n) with probability N(n,X[n]) / (Sum over x in S(N) of N(n,x))

And then you keep building down: given you have already drawn X[n],X[n-1],...,X[i+1] you draw X[i] from S(i) with X[i]<=X[i+1] with probability N(i,X[i]) / (Sum over x in S(i) with x<=X[i+1] of N(i,x))

Comment: Wow! That's really good. It took some time for me to realize that you can actually substitute "Sum over x in S(i) with x<=X[i+1] of N(i,x)" in the denominator with just N(i+1, X[i+1]). And for X[n] the denominator is N(n+1, M), where M is the maximum over S(n). Thus, we can sample with probability N(i, X[i]) / N(i+1, X[i+1]) and it's easy to prove that it's exactly uniform. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of the hueristic I suggested in the comments:

```
import random

def rand_increasing(sets):
    #assume: sets is list of sets

    sets = [s.copy() for s in sets]
    n = len(sets)
    indices = list(range(n))
    random.shuffle(indices)
    chosen = [0]*n

    for i,k in enumerate(indices):
        chosen[k] = random.choice(list(sets[k]))
        for j in indices[(i+1):]:
            if j > k:
                sets[j] = {x for x in sets[j] if x > chosen[k]}
            else:
                sets[j] = {x for x in sets[j] if x < chosen[k]}
    return chosen

#test:
sets = [{8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31},
        {10, 20, 30, 50},
        {1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003}]

for _ in range(10):
    print(rand_increasing(sets))
```

Typical output:

```
[24, 50, 1996]
[26, 30, 2001]
[17, 30, 1995]
[11, 20, 2000]
[12, 20, 1996]
[11, 50, 2003]
[14, 20, 2002]
[9, 10, 2001]
[8, 30, 1999]
[8, 10, 1998]
```

Of course, if you can get uniform sampling with Julien's approach, that is preferable. (This heuristic *might* give uniform -- but that would require proof). Also note that poor choices in the earlier stages might drive some of the later sets in the permutation to being empty, raising an error. The function could be called in a loop with proper error trapping, yielding a hit-or-miss approach.

Comment: Example where this could fail: X[1] in {1,2,...10}, X[2] in {5,15}, X[3] in {10,11,...20}. X[3] is chosen as 12, X[1] is chosen as 8, no choice possible left for X[2] >> will crash... So should probably add some fail safe logic...

Comment: @Julien Good point. That is why I threw in the last couple of sentences. The given function is a heuristic which *attempts* to solve the problem. When it succeeds it should have little to no bias but the cost of using this approach is that it might fail. It can be used in a loop which catches the error and times out after a certain number of  failures.